# How to wrap a group of words with tags, JavaScript Replace Regular Expressions

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I am trying to wrap some words with HTML tags, for that I am using regular expressions. I am almost there:

This is my regexp

```
/((apple|banana|cherry|orange)\b\s?)+/gi
```

and this is my replacement:

```
<em>$&</em>
```

which works perfectly for my example text:

```
Apple Banana apple cherry, Cherry orange and Oranges Apple, Banana
```

the result being:

```
<em>Apple Banana apple cherry</em>, <em>Cherry orange </em>and Oranges <em>Apple</em>, <em>Banana</em>
```

I could be pragmatic and live with this but I would reaaaaaally like to have it perfect and not include the space after the final match.

i.e. my perfect result would be (see the tag shifted left after "Cherry orange"):

```
<em>Apple Banana apple cherry</em>, <em>Cherry orange</em> and Oranges <em>Apple</em>, <em>Banana</em>
```

Comment: Is "Oranges" not supposed to be enclosed in <em>s?

Comment: and why not <em>$&</em> (note the slash)?

Comment: @BipedalShark: that's correct, I only want full and specific words. @nalply: my bad, of course </em>, I just corrected it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't support lookbehind. This is a shame, as we could have done:

```
// doesn't work in JavaScript:
/((apple|banana|cherry|orange)\b\s?)+(?<!\s)/gi
```

What we can do, however, is to move the white-space to the beginning, and add a negative lookahead (so the catch must not start with a white-space):

```
/(?!\s)(\s?\b(apple|banana|cherry|orange)\b)+/gi
```

A slight difference from your code is that I also added `\b` to the beginning of the pattern, so it wouldn't catch `apple` from `Snapple`.

Comment: JavaScript does not have issues with lookbehind, it doesn't support it. Perhaps this is what you meant, but "has issues" suggests (to me) that it *does* support it, but the implementation contains bugs.

Comment: I know, that is what I meant. That's a **big issue**. I agree, Bart,  I'll change it to avoid confusion.

Comment: the `\b` didn't seem to be necessary in my original example.

Awesome thanks!! This was my first question on StackOverflow. I am absolutely amazed I got a perfect answer this quick!

Comment: No problem, Thanks! Welcome to StackOverflow. BTW, it's a very good question, and well formatted. Probably the reason it was up voted that much.

Answer (score 2):

You could put function in the replace parameter as

`function(x){return "<em>"+x.replace(/\s+$/,"")+"<em>";}` instead of `<em>$&</em>`

and you could put striping space inside that function.

```
"Apple Banana apple cherry, Cherry orange and Oranges Apple, Banana".replace(
/((?:apple|banana|cherry|orange)\b\s?)+/gi,
function(x){
   return "<em>"+x.replace(/\s+$/,"")+"<em>";
})

<em>Apple Banana apple cherry<em>, <em>Cherry orange<em>and Oranges <em>Apple<em>, <em>Banana<em>
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate how come the second argument for replace is a function? I can't find any documentation about this behavior.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace - but attention, it is not supported by all browsers (IE5, for example)

Answer (score 0):

You could also solve this with a lookahead at the end of the pattern to make sure that any match is followed by space, a comma or end-of-string (this naturally means a match won't match if the result is followed by a letter, which would be the case in the problematic example).

Altered matching pattern:

```
/((apple|banana|cherry|orange)\b\s?)+(?=\s|,|$)/gi
```